# What is the grammatical form of 待たされていました?

Tags: grammar, conjugations

[Section 2-1: Inflecting](http://pomax.github.io/nrGrammar/#section-2-1-Inflecting) example 待た**され**ていました contradicts the [causative formula](http://pomax.github.io/nrGrammar/#section-3-2-12-Causative:_%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B/%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B)

In the book causative defined as 五段未然形+せる/一段未然形+させる.

待つ is a 五段 verb, so its causative form should be 待たせる, and 連用形 of this should be 待たせ, therefore the verb should be 待た**せ**ていました.

Am I missing something here?

Can someone evaluate the [explanation](http://pomax.github.io/nrGrammar/#section-2-1-Inflecting) of this verb form. Is it correct or not?

Comment: `Can someone evaluate the explanation of this verb form. Is it correct or not?`  I skimmed over the text and to my poor knowledge it seems correct.  However instead of making others read your text of choice it will be more beneficial to you to check other texts yourself - this way you will both be able to gain confidence in the text _and_ perhaps find new useful perspectives on the material in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

待たせた = Made (someone) wait.
待たされた = (someone)Was made to wait.

When the verb becomes causative,
待つ -> 待たす

When the verb changes to passive mode,
待つ -> 待たれる

When a verb becomes causative and then make it passive,
待つ -> 待たす -> 待たされる

Comment: Could you provide a reference to the causative formula (未然形+す). I was not aware of it at all, and would like to learn more about it.

Comment: @user1602 it is the Shortened Causative Form, it is not very used, I just used it for simplicity and because the example you gave seems to be the Shortened causative-passive form. You can take a look at http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/causepass Best website for learning grammar I even found.

Comment: 「[持]{も}つ」？「[待]{ま}つ」？なんか混じってるみたい・・

Comment: @Shoko 恥ずかしいな。ありがとうございました。

Comment: "Progressive" was not even mentioned once...

Comment: @user1602: It's worth noting that the 未然形 + す form is in fact the older form of the causative.  This final す underwent a conjugational shift, resulting in the modern せる ending.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer has it all, but here's a step-by-step inference produced by [GeekJDict](https://github.com/kroki/GeekJDict):

```
geekjdict>> g 待たされていました
 待たされていました is the past form of 待たされています
  待たされています is the polite form of 待たされている
   待たされている is the continuous form of 待たされて
    待たされて is the て-form of 待たされた
     待たされた is the past form of 待たされる
      待たされる is the passive form of 待たす
       see plain 待たす t: v5s
       待たす is the colloquial form of 待たせる
        see causative 待たせる t: v1
        待たせる is the causative form of 待つ
         see plain 待つ t: v5t
```

So 待たす is the colloquial form of 待たせる.  As other comment said, [guidetojapanese.org](http://guidetojapanese.org/) is the best resource on Japanese grammar (and GeekJDict's grammar inference is based on it).

Comment: なにこれすごい...... +1

Comment: ^ bro, でも `待たされている is the continuous form of 待たされて
    待たされて is the て-form of 待たされた
     待たされた is the past form of 待たされる` ってどうなん？「待たされている is the continuous form of またされる」で良くね？ せめて `待たされて is the て-form of 待たされた
     待たされた is the past form of 待たされる` は「待たされて is the て-form of 待たされる」でええやん。なんで過去形入ってくんの

Comment: I was under the impression that て-form is　連用形 of [つ](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/145916/meaning/m0u/) and is not a form of た as geekjdict suggests.

Comment: @Shoko, user1602 you both are correct.  However GeekJDict chooses to show conjugation sub-steps because it's easier to see how, for instance, て-form is constructed from past tense (especially for godan verbs), even if no actual past is involved (GeekJDict follows "minimum information principle", so for instance [て-form rules](https://github.com/kroki/GeekJDict/blob/master/lib/GeekJDict/grammar.rules#L438-L439) do not repeat [past tense rules](https://github.com/kroki/GeekJDict/blob/master/lib/GeekJDict/grammar.rules#L286-L298)).  It's a _machine_ output, it still requires _human_ to interpret.

Comment: The grammar.rule file is composed by a human - not machine, and can be modified to reflect the language reality and not rely on recursion for た

Comment: @user1602 It won't make you a better mathematician if you insist that 8 has nothing to do with infinity symbol ∞ and so shouldn't be used as a mnemonic device.  It won't improve your Japanese if you will learn past tense and て-form separately (will only add more points of potential failure).  It is "the language reality" that た-て/だ-で trick always works.  So why not be bold about it?  We don't talk the way we do _because_ of grammar rules.  They try to capture the language retrospectively, but speech itself is not analytic.  To produce speech brain uses patterns and associations, so help it ;).

Comment: Does @kroki have any evidence to his statement on how brains uses patterns to produce speech? :) The point is that て has nothing to do with た.  You could have chosen to use て to explain た contraction. But this is not the place to discuss this, and probably not the place to promote software

Comment: @user1602 For introductory material on psychology and brain science I'd recommend [The Great Courses](http://www.thegreatcourses.com/category/science/neuroscience-psychology.html) (ups, another advertisement slip).  But you do have a point: paraphrasing Sigmund Freud _"every post is a kind of self-promotion"_ ;).  Regarding た/て I have a suspicion that it goes beyond a mere coincidence, but you seem to have a strong evidence that that's not the case, so I won't argue against that.  Still, it is a useful heuristic rule, and some software we won't mention by name is not shy about that :).

Answer (score 2):

Because words such as 待たせられる mataserareru are considered to be difficult to pronounce, frequently in colloquial speech, the middle part of the causative passive would contract. That is, 待たせられる mataserareru (I was made to wait), would become 待たされる matasareru. Another example such as "(I) was made to buy (something)" would formally be 買わせられた kawaserareta from the verb 買う kau, but colloquially, it is frequently contracted to 買わされた kawasareta. This abbreviation is not used for ichidan verbs, nor for the irregular する suru and くる kuru.